# scalar value as an array? PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, scalar

I'm getting this error:

```
'( ! ) Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\or2LAST\admin\adminData.php on line 5`
```

the code for this error (line 5):

```
$admin['push']=array(
        1=>"yes",
        2=>"no"

);
```

i tried to use "1" & "2" for the key but it didn't solve the problem.

where is the problem and why this error occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declace $admin to an array first

like

```
$admin=array();
```

then try

```
$admin['push']=array(
    1=>"yes",
    2=>"no"

);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `$admin`. You need to declare it as an array before using it:

```
$admin = array();
```

Whatever it is now, it's *not* an array. Possibly on a previous line you're overwriting it with some new (scalar) value instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with variable $admin, following should work just fine (assuming $admin is not previously declared).

```
$admin = array(); //<--!!
$admin['push']=array(
    1=>"yes",
    2=>"no"

);
```